# Window.alert() event in gwt

Tags: events, gwt, window, alert

I have one doubt, What happening if we press OK button in Window.alert in gwt? Is there any event happening backside if we pressed OK button?

Answer (score 13):

`Window.alert()` is a blocking call, so upon clicking *OK* the code resumes running.

```
Window.alert("OK?");
GWT.log("That line won't run until after you dismiss the alert box, "
      + "THAT's the \"event\"!");
```