# how to stop control for each if statements using gwt

Tags: gwt, if-statement

I am using GWT. In my program many if conditions there. At the end of each if condition i put window.alert box. If i click OK button, then only next if condition will execute. I don't want alert boxes in each if conditions.Instead of this any other solution is there?

Comment: I think your intention of putting the alerts is for logging. If that is the case then you should be using GWT.log("message") which will print the log message in the hosted browser window.

Answer (score 0):

> Window.alert() is a blocking call, so upon clicking OK the code
>   resumes running

([quoted from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18761088/1722236)).

You can either use [modals](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/gwt-bootstrap/apidocs/com/github/gwtbootstrap/client/ui/Modal.html)/pop-ups or a logger ([GWT logging framework documentation here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html)) to display alerts/logs respectively.